# Firebase set data from database as variable

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just started using Firebase and i can't get data from database. Here's my code

```
const books = firebase.database().ref('Books');
var index;
books.once("value", function(snapshot) {
   index = snapshot.val().Count
});

console.log(index)
```

Console log gives `undefined`. Where's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please try console.log(snapshot.val()) inside the callback function and let me know the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do this:

```
const books = firebase.database().ref('Books');
var index;
books.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  index = snapshot.val().Count
}).then(function() {
  console.log(index)
});
```

What's happening is that the data is temporary and if you try to read 'index' from outside the Firebase function, 'index' would be empty and it would return null, resulting in 'undefined' so you need to put the 'console.log' function either in the 'then(func())' function or with the variable set function in the 'once(action, func())' function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is that book.once is asynchronious, so what's actually happening in your code is this.

```
//set reference to books
//set variable index to undefined
//start a call to update index
//log the value of index
//call to update value finishes, index gets set to something
```

try moving your console.log inside the books.once block, and see that the value gets logged.

Comment: The output is correct, but i need this value to be global. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It depends on how you define global. You could look into async-await, or you could chain a then off of the call, but inevitably you're going to have to wait for the call to complete one way or another

Answer (score 0):

Your call is asynchronous and `console.log` gets executed even though `.once()` has not finished yet.

Do this:

```
books.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  index = snapshot.key; // Count doesn't exist, the index is called "key" in firebase
  return snapshot.val();
}).then(function(books) {
  // This basically makes sure that the .once() callback has been done. Now you can see what's in `books`.
  console.log(books);
});
```

Edit: You can't access the `.val()` of `books` outside of an asynchronous operation. [Take a look here for more about async operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).